# How to download file from Windows Container in Rancher?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, rancher

I have deployed an application in a windows container, It's working as expected. I can browse the file as well using commands like `cd`, `dir` and `more` in its shell. and see its content. But these are very large files so it's a very bad experience in seeing the content of the file. Is there any way to download these files on the local system, so that I can use notepad or notepadd++ type tool to view the content?

As answered by @gohm'c below, I have run the below command, but it's giving the below error.

```
kubectl cp fxtrader-559547b674-x9wtn:/Logs/MyApp/2022/02/MyApp_2022-02-10-02.log abc.txt
```

**Error:**

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connectex:
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the file over to your local disk like `kubectl cp <pod name>:<path to the file in Windows container WITHOUT drive letter> <local file path>`. Example: `kubectl cp busybox:/data/file/huge.logs ./huge.logs`

Comment: and where should I run his command?

Comment: On your local machine where you can communicate with your cluster with `kubectl`.

Comment: I have run the above command, But it's giving an error. Please check my updated question.

Comment: This error is not related to the command. You simply don't have a working kubeconfig. See [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/cluster-admin/cluster-access/kubectl/) how to setup one.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: Getting thie error now Error from server (Forbidden): pods "fxtrader-559547b674-x9wtn" is forbidden: User "u-o7myw6ruw6" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Comment: You don't have sufficient permission.

Comment: Is there any way to pass credentials in the above command?

Comment: Could you check firewall or anything that could block network connectivity?